# GE Refrigerator Low Voltage at Water Inlet Valve

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

I have a French Door GE Refrigerator model GFE24JSKPFSS that has no water coming out of the dispenser and no ice.

I have good water flow into the water inlet value, and the valve measures 360 ohms across the valve contacts points. I tested with a cheater cord and the valve opens with good flow once 120 VAC is applied to the contacts.

When the water dispenser is pressed, I'm only getting about 20-22 VAC from the plug that plugs into the inlet valve.

Any ideas on what causes that low voltage or what to try next?

Comment: do you have the OM manual

Comment: @Ruskes I haven't been able to find a copy of it. I can look for one. Anything specific to look at?

Comment: new water dispenser

Comment: Might be a manual online if you can't find it.  I usually find search much faster than tearing the house apart.

Comment: Some possibilities are a bad control board, broken wire, bad switch, bad terminal for starters.

Comment: @Gil everything visually looks fine. I haven't taken anything apart by the water dispenser to test that. Is there any way to really test that main control board?

Comment: The only think you can do is check the voltage back to the board and if it is not coming out and the switch is OK it would have to be the main board. Any bad connection in the solenoid wiring or switch could cause the problem. I am assuming it is a 120V solenoid as you indicated but it is possible it is 24VAC but I have no way of knowing without the manual. If there are other solenoids what voltage are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find this service manual. Not for exactly my model but it looks the same and appears to match everything. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1662427/Ge-Gye18jbl.html?page=31#manual

There is a second valve in the door the manual calls the Dual Valve that is working fine, measured 120 volts there when the dispenser is running. It should be powered off the same line off the main board, so not sure why I'm only measuring 20 or so at the Isolation Valve at the back of the fridge when it should be 60 or 120 volts (there's a diode on that line).

What I ended up doing was just bypassing the inlet valve at the back completely, connecting the water line from the house directly to the line to the water filter. So the Dual Valve is pressurized at all times now, but water and ice both work. $4 fix, and it seems to be working fine.